# Unable to install PHPUnit pear package in XAMPP

Tags: php, windows-7, phpunit, xampp, pear

Here is my problem. I already asked that question in the XAMPP community forum
but no reply. Maybe some of you can help.

I am running XAMPP with the following config

- Win 7, 32 bit
- xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6

I want to update PHPUnit via pear that I can use it for Selenium Testing

First, add I the Channel

pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

Then I install package

pear install phpunit/PHPUnit

Right here I get always the same error message ...

```
Warning: file_exists (): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you forget to
enable it when you configured PHP? in PEAR \ Downloader \ Package.php on line 1416

Warning: is_file (): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you forget to ena
ble it when you configured PHP? in PEAR \ Downloader \ Package.php on line 1425

Warning: is_file (): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you forget to ena
ble it when you configured PHP? in PEAR \ Downloader \ Package.php on line 1425
```

I even tried to reinstall xampp completely, which didn't helped.

I also did an

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Didn't changed a thing.

Can this be due to an firefall setting?

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Best regards

Jeremy

Comment: updated my answer with a workaround for you pear update problem

Comment: I have managed to upgrade to ***version 1.9.2*** but when i run pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit I get `Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony-project.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeremy,

I have the exact same set-up on my pc environment...

Win 7, 32 bit
xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6

1. what version pear is installed on you system...type " pear info pear " (without quotes).
2. You need version 1.9.1 at least. If not type " pear upgrade pear "
3. Tip - open cmd open as administrator - it makes a huge difference
4. also try " pear remote-list -c phpunit " to discover packages you have in phpunit
5. and either " pear install phpunit/the_package_name "

It worked for me - I hope this helps...There are other ways but I find this the most effective way with xampp 1.7.4 in windows 7

Comment: ***pear info pear*** shows version 1.7.2, unfortunaely ***pear upgrade pear*** hangs and won't upgrade. I have opend the CMD as administrator but with no effect. Is there maybe a log file where I can see whats happening during upgrade? Can this be an firewall problem/access rights problem because of Win7 restrictive access rights?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
pear install --force pear
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Post a comment if it doesn't work and I'll investigate further

**Pear update Problems?**

To update your PEAR installation, request http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar in your browser and save the output to a local file `go-pear.php`. You can then run

```
php go-pear.php
```

If that doesn't work start the shell with admin privileges (rightclick -> run as admin).

**Reponse to the comment:**

If pear tells you that it doesn't know about a channel like `pear.symfony-project.com` you need to run:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `C:\Users\nameuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\cache`, where `nameuser` is your Windows username.

In this folder, delete all temporary lines and then try to update with the above steps.